# How to do aligning image next to textbox with CSS?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am having difficulty in aligning an image next to a text box with CSS file.

I have tried this solution but the output is wrong, please check the code below and attached image.

Thank you.

**aspx page:**

```
                <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
                    <label for="Date">Date</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Date" runat="server" CssClass="pure-u-23-24"></asp:TextBox>
                    <img src="/Images/calen.gif" id="Img1" alt="Date" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'"
                        onmouseout="this.style.cursor='default'" class="image" />
                <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Date"
                    PopupButtonID="Img1" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" Animated="true"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Date"
                    SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Date" Text="*" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Validation4" CssClass="validation-summary-errors-one"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>
```

**CSS file:**

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
}
```

**Output in browser:**

[image]

**Edit #1**

```
<img src="/Images/calen.gif" id="Date" alt="Date" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'"
    onmouseout="this.style.cursor='default'" style="float:left;" />
```

Comment: try to use `float` property [CSS float Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the **Control ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender** in **Markup** on the aspx page, why do you need an image and CSS (you need to know how to use them) to call the calendar ?

Change your code with this suggestion and you will simply need to click on the box to change the Date value.

Hope this helps!

```
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
        <label for="Date">Date</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Date" runat="server" CssClass="pure-u-23-24"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Date"
        Format="dd/MM/yyyy" Animated="true"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Date"
        SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Date" Text="*" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Validation4" CssClass="validation-summary-errors-one"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for suggestion ... it working !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `float: left;` on the .image class and then alter the positioning if required.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="pure-u-1" ...>
    <asp:TextBox ...></asp:TextBox>
    <img class="image" .../>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pure-u-1 { position: relative; }
.image { position: absolute; left: .5em; top: .2em; }
```

Pure-u-1 class have relative position with no left/top position specified. But it becomes the begin point for relative/absolute/fixed positioning of it's children elements.

Comment: thank you but if change the class in div and use Pure-u-1 class I lost the original CSS formatting

Comment: Are you able to add your own class to the parent <div> element? If not, are you able to add any custom parameter/value?
You could then use div[mytextbox=true] { position: relative; } as CSS and <div mytextbox="true"> as HTML code.
See CSS3 selectors' list for more options http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp - hope something help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't know aspx or what styles might be attached to the various css classes on your elements. When I rebuild this with the simplest html elements they all line up in one row.

My guesses:

1. (not knowing whether this is the full width of your container or just a cut screenshot:) maybe your textbox is too wide for the image to fit so try reducing the size and check your margins.
2. add "display: inline" to your textbox and/or
3. add "vertical-align: middle" to your textbox OR
4. add "float:left" to your textbox, then adjust the position of your image.

I would avoid using float though since that is not the intended use for it and leads to misleading code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In Control TextBox on ASP NET it's not possible add style properties ... only CssClass ....

Comment: In that case can you not add the styles I suggest above in your stylesheet? So:
.pure-u-23-24 {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

Comment: Thank you I have tried, I don't have changes in html page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `float: left;`, you must set width for element like that:

```
.pure-u-1{
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
}
.pure-u-1 label{
    width: 30px;
    float: left;
}
.pure-u-1 input{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
.pure-u-1 img{
    width: 66px;
    float: left;
}
```

I created example, hope this helps [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vgLtymw/1/)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have only element Date in my webpage, if change Div all other Div in webpage are changed ...

Comment: you can set class for element, just example for float property

Comment: Please check Edit #1 in my first question, the output not change.

Comment: condition to use float property: width image + width textbox <= width div 'pure-u-1'. In your code width textbox = width div =>> image can not float